# What's the difference between I want it and I want to have it?

Tags: sentence-choice, sentence-usage

What's the difference between:

> I want it

> I want to have it

And what is the reason?

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145282/whats-the-difference-between-i-want-it-and-i-want-to-have-it/

Comment: It's the link of here

Comment: haha, i meant this: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/144078/want-a-look-vs-want-to-have-a-look?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You said it's okay to say have it, but, in the board of the link above, It's not okay to say have a look.

Comment: Not sure I understand. In the other question, I say "want a look" and "want to have a look" are interchangeable

Comment: Now I'm comfused

Comment: I added some more example sentences to my answer below.

Comment: Very little difference between the two and in most cases they are interchangeable. 
The slight difference can been seen in the following -- Things I want: *world peace, happy and successful children, a robust job market*.  Things I want to have: *new car, a good job, two children*.

Comment: "I want _to pee_" and "I want to have _to pee_" are quite different.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a slight difference between the two. So little that both can be used in place of each other without changing the actual meaning of the sentence.
'want to have it" is a stronger urge to get something than 'want it'.

Comment: This is the opposite of what I thought. Now I'm confused.

Comment: It's true, there is a movie called "She's Got to Have It," which means she has a very strong urge. But that is a slang expression that's different from the example in my answer. In my example and probably some others, "want to have [noun]" is less emphatic than "want [noun]."

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much difference, as far as I can tell. There might be more immediacy and emphasis to ***want*** than ***want to have***. For example:

> He wants sex.
>
> He wants to have sex.

People might disagree, but I think ***he wants sex*** could connote a stronger or more spontaneous urge than ***he wants to have sex***, which connotes a more deliberate or more formalized or less immediate action.

EDIT: Adding some more examples just so people can draw conclusions for themselves:

> I want the kidney transplant.
>
> I want to have the kidney transplant.
>
> The CEO wanted the Ferrari.
>
> The CEO wanted to have the Ferrari.
>
> The dog wants a kiss.
>
> The dog wants to have a kiss.
>
> We wanted a World Series championship.
>
> We wanted to have a World Series championship.

Looking at these examples, I still believe ***wants to have*** implies a more deliberate or more formalized action. The desire in ***wants*** is perhaps more ephemeral or spontaneous.

For example, it's a tiny bit awkward to say ***The dog wants to have a kiss*** because it implies that the dog is thinking about it and has made a conscious decision that he would like you to kiss him. We know dogs don't reason in this way, so it's a little humorous to say a dog wants to have a kiss. Instead, we would say, "The dog wants a kiss." It's a simple, spontaneous desire.

Comment: The example is awesome

Comment: Haha, yeah, I just wanted something simple to understand but not boring.

Comment: @haruto I edited my answer again, i added an explanation of the dog example at the very bottom. Maybe this can clarify things a little

Answer (score 1):

Cheers Ringo for great examples and sound reasoning. I wasn't sure but you have me sold. Rereading this I get a feeling that "to have" has a slightly different feel to it, using the Ferrari example (as an example),  "I want to have" says something about continued possession of the Ferrari but I'm just sleep deprived and also really bad at both speaking and comprehending the English language and you obviously are not.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. When the CEO goes to the dealership, he wants the Ferrari (spontaneous desire). And he wants to have the Ferrari to impress his many girlfriends (continuous desire).